# FusionTablesLayer Polygon with styleId click event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, dom-events

I have a fusion table that I want to use with a styleid to configure the appearance. It seems that a FusionTablesLayer with a styleid cannot have a click event attached.

Here is an example of the FusionTablesLayerOptions I am using:

```
settings: {
    query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '<<my table id>>'
    },
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    styleId: 2
}
```

And here is the click event that does not fire:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(<<my FusionTablesLayer obj>>, 'click', function () {
    console.log('layer click');
});
```

When I change the FusionTablesLayerOptions to this, the event does fire:

```
settings: {
    query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '<<my table id>>'
    },
    suppressInfoWindows: true
}
```

So my question is - do you think that layers with a styleId don't support click events? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it:

1. There is a "styledId" property in FusionTablesLayerOptions and its documented [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles)
2. This issue was being caused by the opacity of the polygon fill color. Seems that if the opacity of a polygon fill is set to 0% then no click events attached to the layer will fire. Setting the opacity to 1% fixed this issue straight away. I have added an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up37D.jpg) to demonstrate.

Comment: Did you give us a link to your table so we could have known that?

Comment: Nah - fusion table link wouldn't have made any difference. Its common throughout the fusion tables API that when setting opacity of polygon or stroke the number must be 1% or higher eg: 0.01.

Comment: How could we tell the opacity you were using?

Comment: You wouldn't. However from the example I gave it's obvious that the issue is style related. The issue was present with the styleId value set and not present without it. Also this is the only known issue with fusion tables styles resulting in this specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "styledId" property in FusionTablesLayerOptions.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions

Please check the official document:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles

Comment: Nah there is a "styledId" property in FusionTablesLayerOptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a styleId property documented [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles), doesn't seem to have made it into the Google Maps API v3 Documentation yet.

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-US&fromgroups=#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/EceabeRWqWc) in the Fusion Tables Users Group for more information.  Seems like others are having the same issue.

How many maps tabs do you have in the new look?  Maybe you need a different styleId number.