# How do I make it so that a user can change the colors of a layer in Google Fusion Tables?

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

My website uses Fusion Tables. The problem, they use red and green, which are not colorblind-friendly.

I'd like to add an option where users can change the color-scheme they see to something else (like Blue-Orange, for example).

Is this possible using the Google Fusion Tables Javascript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you own the FusionTables with the data in them?  You can now have multiple styles available created with the UI.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812749/fusiontableslayer-polygon-with-styleid-click-event-not-firing) for more details.

Another option is [dynamically styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles) them in javascript, don't know if that will work for your FusionTables or not.

Comment: oh dear, this seems to mean that I'll need to make a new "map" tab in each of my Fusion Tables, huh? Well, if there's no other way, then I'll just have to do that. Am I correct, or did I miss something while reading your answer (and the Google Fusion Table Group Thread in your answer)?

Comment: Added the possible option to do it in javascript. Think that styling them in the UI might be the easiest and best option, but depends on what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the JavaScript option wouldn't work out too well with my Fusion Tables. Still, at least now I know what I must do. Thank you.